# Captar tamanho e extensão de um arquivo e informar via HTML

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tenho uma listagem de arquivos em uma página que estou desenvolvendo. 
O HTML está assim:

```
<li class="downloadsCont">
<div class="grid_365 f-left">
    <div class="downloadsContImg f-left">
        <img src="fotoSYS&w=290" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid_540 f-left">
    <div class="downloadsTit margin-top-35">
            <h2>tituloSYS</h2>
<span>descricaoSYS</span>
<i>Tamanho: 348Kb</i>
<i>Tipo: .PDF</i>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="downloadsBt margin-top-15">
    <div class="downloadsBtText">Download</div>
</div>
```

O que quero, é que onde está informado o `<i>` ele mostre o tamanho do arquivo e também o formato. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Esse arquivo será gerenciado pelo nosso gerenciados próprio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos lá... Você vai conseguir fazer as duas coisas usando o PHP...

### Extensão do arquivo

PHP: `public string SplFileInfo::getExtension ( void )`

Exemplo:

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('foo.txt');
var_dump($info->getExtension());
```

Você vai alocar o `var_dump` em uma variável qualquer, dai você chama ele e ele dará a extensão do arquivo para você.

### Quanto ao tamanho do Arquivo

Para o tamanho do arquivo, use: `int filesize ( string $filename )`.
Exemplo:

```
$filename = 'arquivo.txt';
echo $filename . ': ' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes';
```

Na dúvida, poderá recorrer a doc. oficial do PHP: [filesize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filesize.php) e [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)

---

### Código com PHP

```
<div class="grid_365 f-left">
    <div class="downloadsContImg f-left"><img alt="" src=
    "fotoSYS&w=290"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid_540 f-left">
    <div class="downloadsTit margin-top-35">
        <h2>tituloSYS</h2><span>descricaoSYS</span> 
        <i>Tamanho: <?php echo $fileSize ?></i>
        <i>Tipo: <?php echo $fileType ?></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="downloadsBt margin-top-15">
    <div class="downloadsBtText">
        Download
    </div>
</div>
```